# Is it correct to add reference directly yo packages folder?

Tags: nuget

Is it correct to add reference directly yo packages folder?

if not, what is the correct way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way is to add the package to each project that needs the reference.  I believe right clicking the solution and selecting manage nuget packages allows you to add the reference to multiple projects at the same time

Comment: Thanks. I tested it myself. Installing a package adds an automatic reference too.