# Validating that references to NuGet packages are proper NuGet references

Tags: nuget, dependency-management

I'm moving my large project to properly use NuGet packages. However, I know that [although they shouldn't](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8590696/is-it-correct-to-add-reference-directly-yo-packages-folder), some developers will simply add references to assemblies in `packages`, rather than properly add NuGet refs, and I want to prevent that.

Is there a solution that either:

- Checks this inside Visual Studio, and suggests the correct ref instead?
- Checks this in build time, and produces build errors?

Answer (score 0):

NuGet doesn't have any built-in command to validate this, however it would be relatively simple to write some code to do this.

The basic steps are:

```
for each project in solution
  for each reference in project
    if reference in path 'packages'
      if package not in 'packages.config'
        log 'invalid reference: use NuGet'
```

Comment: I figured as much, and started writing some .targets + custom task for this, will share when ready.